# Access page via a Gravity form submission only

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a multi-stage form created with Gravity Forms. Upon successful completion I've set up a redirect so that the user is sent to a WooCommerce product page. I want that to be the only way for that page to be accessed as they need to have completed the form before they can be allowed to purchase the product. They don't have to register on the site so membership roles can't be used.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to accomplish this. A simple (but very clunky) way is to password protect the Product page and then provide the password to the user via the confirmation message of the form. This is a less than ideal user experience...

An alternate solution is to set a cookie when the form is submitted. On the Product page, you can set a filter via WordPress' "the_content" hook to show/hide the contents of the page depending on whether that cookie is set. I have [an awesome Gravity Forms plugin](http://gravitywiz.com/submit-gravity-form-access-content/) for this but here are the basics:

**Set Cookie on Form Submission**

```
add_action( 'gform_pre_submission', 'set_form_submitted_cookie' );
function set_form_submitted_cookie( $form ) {
    setcookie( 'gf_form_submitted', $form['id'], null, '/' );
}
```

**Check if Cookie Exists**

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'maybe_hide_the_content' );
function maybe_hide_the_content( $content ) {

    if( ! isset( $_COOKIE['gf_form_submitted'] ) ) {
        $content = 'You do not have access to this page.'
    }

    return $content;
}
```

**All Wrapped Up with a Pretty Bow**

If you don't want to touch any code, I've packaged this up into a more robust plugin. You can read more about it here:

http://gravitywiz.com/submit-gravity-form-access-content/